# Get top level index from a nested for function

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have an array of arrays of integers (which is an `[[Int]]`) that represents any given month of the year (sections are weeks and rows are days so month[0][2] would return a `3` if you have a month that starts on a Sunday) I am trying to traverse through the array and find a date and then have it return an IndexPath but I am having trouble.  So far I have this:

```
for (index, week) in monthInfo.enumerated() {
    for (index, day) in week.enumerated() {
        if day == dateComponents.day /* Today's Date (the day I'm looking for) */ {
            selectedDay = IndexPath(row: index, section: ???)
        }
    }
}
```

I know  I can get the index of the day from this but I am not sure how to get the index of the week so that I can make a full IndexPath.  Any suggestions?  Or even better, how to do this better?

Comment: I know nothing about swift, but would it not be better to call the index variable in the second loop something different, like "dayIndex"?

Comment: You could also replace the inner loop by `if let dayIndex = week.index(of: dateComponents.day) { ... }`

Comment: @MartinR thanks, that saves some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are in control of your tuples, you can rename `index` in one or in both of them to disambiguate:

```
for (indexWeek, week) in monthInfo.enumerated() {
    for (indexDay, day) in week.enumerated() {
        if day == dateComponents.day /* Today's Date (the day I'm looking for) */ {
            selectedDay = IndexPath(row: indexDay, section: indexWeek)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to rewrite this so it doesn't keep searching after it finds a match.